What does the name of Amalek mean?
I know there are various etymological methods that scientists use to say "we don't really know where this word comes from" but I'm wondering about what Jewish methods we can apply to understand the name Amalek.
While I am a relatively uneducated Jew, to my eye, עמלק appears to be ayin-prefixed מ-ל-ק which itself seems to be related to מ-ל-ך king.
I don't know much about the individual values of letters but I get this feeling that letters which are visually similar are also often semantically similar. And in this case I see kaf becoming quf as a sort of "corruption" which is compounded by the initial ayin to make Amalek, the word, to me, seem to be essentially a corrupted, twisted version of Melech.
As a modern analogy in case I'm making no sense, considering Amalek to be the nemesis of Israel, I see a situation very similar to Luigi and Waluigi. Or if you imagine a Mr. Kushnir and his evil nemesis Mr. Qoshner.
How does this reasoning compare to other styles of reasoning? Is it okay to read into Amalek in this way? Are there any serious flaws with my thought process? Are there sages who have written on the etymology of this name in a way that concretely answers the question?
As a related question, is there any significance in ayin that I'm not aware of?

Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66180/ (and comments)

I’ve heard a theory that identifies Amalek with the “Lukka people” (which in Hebrew would translate to עם הלקי) mentioned in the Amarna letters as one of the Sea Peoples.

כ exchanges with ק (e.g., כובע/קובע) not because they look similar but because they sound similar

According to Rav S.R. Hirsch, the letter ע indicates motion

Welcome to MiYodeya Bezalel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The midrashim point to it being a contraction of two words "עם לק" lit. "a people who lick (blood)".
For example, refer to the Yalkut Shimoni 983:

דבר אחר עמלק עם לק שבא ללוק דמן של ישראל ככלב
Alternatively, Amalek is (derived from an amalgam of "עם לק") a people that lick i.e. that come to lick from the blood of Israel like a dog.

Famously, from a gematriah (numerical) perspective, the Hebrew word "עמלק" equates to the Hebrew word "ספק" - "doubt" as they help to sow the seeds of confusion and discord.
Also refer to @Fred's answer here who sources from Rav Schneur Zalman of Liadi who...

breaks the name of the nation into component words "עם מלק" ("'am malak") meaning "severed nation" in that the nation's metaphysical brain and heart are severed at the neck.


The interpretation עם מלק can also refer to the death of Eisav (separation of intellect and emotion), when Hushim ben Dan hit his head and it separated from Eisav's body. It is a reference to the process of melikah when a kohen separates a head of a bird with his nail during a sacrifice (Vayikra 1:15). One can use this idea to explain why G-d make Yaakov's neck strong like marble when Eisav sought to bite his neck.
I also heard, in the name of R. Gedalia Schorr, that Amaleq can also be read עמל קוף - monkey labor, i.e. the nation that does not produce anything, imitates labor activity, and lives off stealing and preying on its neighbors. (For example, all types of socialist regimes need periodic wars because their economy is not efficient enough to sustain).
